# Запись результата выполнения sql запроса в переменную

Tags: python, sqlite, циклы, tuple

Учусь в python работать с sqlite.

Столкнулся с тем, что при выполнении запроса в БД не могу записать данные в переменную :

```py
rows = c.execute("SELECT message_id From Messages where DATE is NOT Null")
for row in rows.fetchall():
        print(row[0])
```

Т.к. кортеж, который возвращается я обрабатываю в цикле, чтобы убрать лишнее - '[', то сообщения выводятся списком по 1, что не совсем то что нужно.
Необходимо полный результат запроса записать в переменную и вывести ее.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно это сделать?

Comment: В переменной какого типа и в каком виде вы хотите видеть "весь результат" ?

Comment: str , т.к. там текстовые значения

Comment: хорошо, вот пришло вам 3 значения "aaa", "bbb" и "ccc" как одна строковая переменная должна выглядеть ?

Comment: aaa, bbb, ccc
Или если есть возможность, записать через /n
aaa
bbb
ccc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fetchall нам возвращает фактически массив [ ['aaa'], ['bbb'], ['ccc'] ]. Значит нам его сначала надо привести к массиву вида ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'], а потом уже собрать в строку так, как нужно. Сборка массива в строку происходит с помощью join. Итого:

```
string = ', '.join( [ row[0] for row in rows.fetchall() ] )
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно :)